# twitter msg automatically post to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

Am not sure there is a feature like ,

automatically update twitter tweet in to facebook ,

May i know is there any like automatic update ,

For Should i use API or CURL , or anything else ,

Thanks

just i find one thread from google

[link text](http://mashable.com/2009/05/25/twitter-to-facebook/)

Is there any thing else then this thread...

Comment: ...what? You want to write a twitter client that crossposts to facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the [twitter application](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=2231777543&ref=s&ref=s) on facebook. There is more helpful information [here](http://michaelhyatt.com/2009/02/how-to-update-your-facebook-status-with-twitter.html)

Comment: Hi , twitter and facebook connects working fine,
but i want tweet updates in the FB News Feed page ,
At present updates showing only in this location http://apps.facebook.com/twitter/,

Comment: If you set the twitter facebook application to post to your wall it will. I think that is the default. If it is not working ofr you, try removing the applicaiton and then re-adding it with the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple existing ways to do this. As Shadi suggested you can use the official twitter app. or if you would like more control on what is sent to facebook you can use [tweelay.net](http://tweelay.net) (full disclosure: i am the sole developer of tweelay)

If you wanted to roll your own:

I suggest using the Twitter Streaming API backed up by a standard [statuses/home_timeline](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-home_timeline) call from a cron job every minute or so to grab tweets. then with the tweets you can send them to facebook using the Graph API.

There are several existing [libraries](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries) that can be used to get you started.